# How to merge async generators into a vanilla generator in python 3.5+

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm having trouble combining async generators and actually running them. This is because the only way I 've found to run them is through an event loop which returns an iterable and not a generator. Let me illustrate this with a simple example:

Let's say I have a function google_search that searches google by scraping it (I'm not using the API on purpose). It takes in a search string and returns a generator of search results. This generator doesn't end when the page is over, the function continues by going on to the next page. Therefore the google_search function returns a possibly nearly endless generator (it will technically always end but often you can get millions of hits for a search on google)

```
def google_search(search_string):
    # Basically uses requests/aiohttp and beautifulsoup
    # to parse the resulting html and yield search results
    # Assume this function works
    ......
```

Okay, so now I want to make a function that allows me to iterate over multiple google_search generators. I'd like something like this:

```
def google_searches(*search_strings):
    for results in zip(google_search(query) for query in search_strings):
        yield results
```

This way I can use a simple for loop to unwind google_searches and get my results. And the above code works well but is very slow for any reasonably big number of searches. The code is sending a request for the first search, then the second and so forth until finally, it yields results. I would like to speed this up (a lot). My first idea is to change google_searches to an async function  (I am using python 3.6.3 and can use await/async etc). This then creates an async generator which is fine but I can only run it in another async function or an event loop. And running it in an event loop with run_until_complete(loop.gather(...)) returns a list of results instead of a normal generator, which defeats the purpose as there's probably way too many search results to hold in a list.

How can I make the google_searches function faster (using preferably async code but anything is welcomed) by executing requests asynchronously while still having it be a vanilla generator?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my question not properly asked or not specific? I don't mind the downvote but I'd like to know what's wrong so I can improve upon it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accepted answer waits for one result from EACH async generator before calling the generators again. If data doesn't come at the same exact same pace, that may be a problem. The solution below takes multiple async iterables (generators or not) and iterates all of them simultaneously in multiple coroutines. Each coroutine puts the results in a `asyncio.Queue`, which is then iterated by the client code:

**Iterator code:**

```
import asyncio
from async_timeout import timeout

class MergeAsyncIterator:
    def __init__(self, *it, timeout=60, maxsize=0):
        self._it = [self.iter_coro(i) for i in it]
        self.timeout = timeout
        self._futures = []
        self._queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=maxsize)

    def __aiter__(self):
        for it in self._it:
            f = asyncio.ensure_future(it)
            self._futures.append(f)
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        if all(f.done() for f in self._futures) and self._queue.empty():
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        with timeout(self.timeout):
            try:
                return await self._queue.get()
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                raise StopAsyncIteration

    def iter_coro(self, it):
        if not hasattr(it, '__aiter__'):
            raise ValueError('Object passed must be an AsyncIterable')
        return self.aiter_to_queue(it)

    async def aiter_to_queue(self, ait):
        async for i in ait:
            await self._queue.put(i)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

**Sample client code:**

```
import random
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

async def myaiter(name):
    for i in range(5):
        n = random.randint(0, 3)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1 + n)
        yield (name, n)
    yield (name, 'DONE')

async def main():
    aiters = [myaiter(i) for i in 'abc']
    async for i in MergeAsyncIterator(*aiters, timeout=3):
        print(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'), i)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**Output:**

```
14:48:28.638975 ('a', 1)
14:48:29.638822 ('b', 2)
14:48:29.741651 ('b', 0)
14:48:29.742013 ('a', 1)
14:48:30.639588 ('c', 3)
14:48:31.742705 ('c', 1)
14:48:31.847440 ('b', 2)
14:48:31.847828 ('a', 2)
14:48:31.847960 ('c', 0)
14:48:32.950166 ('c', 1)
14:48:33.948791 ('a', 2)
14:48:34.949339 ('b', 3)
14:48:35.055487 ('c', 2)
14:48:35.055928 ('c', 'DONE')
14:48:36.049977 ('a', 2)
14:48:36.050481 ('a', 'DONE')
14:48:37.050415 ('b', 2)
14:48:37.050966 ('b', 'DONE')
```

PS: The code above uses the [`async_timeout`](https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout) third-party library.
PS2: The [`aiostream`](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream) library does the same as the above code and much more.

Comment: Awesome! I'm still surprised there's no easier/more pythonic way of doing this...

Comment: By the way, this solution is roughly equivalent to the `aiostream` [`merge`](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.merge) operator

Answer (score 5):

```
def google_search(search_string):
    # Basically uses requests/aiohttp and beautifulsoup
```

This is plain synchronous generator. You would be able to use `requests` inside it, but if you want to use asynchronous `aiohttp`, you would need [asynchronous generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) defined with `async def`.

What comes to iterating over multiple async generators it's more interesting. You can't use plain `zip` since it works with plain iterables, not async iterables. So you should implement your own (that would also support iterating concurrently).

I made a little prototype that I think does what you want:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time


# async versions of some builtins:
async def anext(aiterator):
    try:
        return await aiterator.__anext__()
    except StopAsyncIteration as exc:
        raise exc


def aiter(aiterable):
    return aiterable.__aiter__()


async def azip(*iterables):
    iterators = [aiter(it) for it in iterables]
    while iterators:
        results = await asyncio.gather(
            *[anext(it) for it in iterators],
            return_exceptions=True,
        )
        yield tuple(results)


# emulating grabbing:
async def request(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()


async def google_search(search_string):
    for i in range(999):  # big async generator
        url = 'http://httpbin.org/delay/{}'.format(i)  # increase delay to better see concurency
        j = await request(url)
        yield search_string + ' ' + str(i)


async def google_searches(*search_strings):
    async for results in azip(*[google_search(s) for s in search_strings]):
        for result in results:
            yield result


# test it works:
async def main():
    async for result in google_searches('first', 'second', 'third'):
        print(result, int(time.time()))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

**Output:**

```
first 0 1514759561
second 0 1514759561
third 0 1514759561
first 1 1514759562
second 1 1514759562
third 1 1514759562
first 2 1514759564
second 2 1514759564
third 2 1514759564
first 3 1514759567
second 3 1514759567
third 3 1514759567
```

Time shows that different searches run concurrently.

Comment: This is beautiful. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! And happy New Year!

Comment: By the way, this solution is roughly equivalent to the `aiostream` [`zip`](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.zip) operator

Comment: I didn't know about aiostream, so thx! But aiostream's merge is even better as I wanted iterators to run until completion.

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to paste here the solution I coded a while ago because I always end up in this question just to remember I already solved this problem before.

```
async def iterator_merge(iterators: typing.Dict[typing.AsyncIterator, typing.Optional[asyncio.Future]]):
while iterators:
    for iterator, value in list(iterators.items()):
        if not value:
            iterators[iterator] = asyncio.ensure_future(iterator.__anext__())

    tasks, _ = await asyncio.wait(iterators.values(), return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    for task in tasks:
        # We send the result up
        try:
            res = task.result()
            yield res
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            # We remove the task from the list
            for it, old_next in list(iterators.items()):
                if task is old_next:
                    logger.debug(f'Iterator {it} finished consuming')
                    iterators.pop(it)
        else:
            # We remove the task from the key
            for it, old_next in list(iterators.items()):
                if task is old_next:
                    iterators[it] = None
```

It has typing annotations, but I think it's a good solution this one. It's meant to be called with your async generators as keys, and a future if you have any to wait.

```
iterators = {
    k8s_stream_pod_log(name=name): None,
    k8s_stream_pod_events(name=name): None,
}
```

You can find it how I use it in github.com/txomon/abot.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining a bit more though? I'm not sure I fully understand your code.